# How much damage does Frostbite do in Zombies In Spaceland?

Tags: call-of-duty-infinite-warfare

I think the title explains the question, but I'll get into the nitty-gritty of it.

This Wonder Weapon costs 500 tickets to buy from the Arcade, and I would like to know if this is a good investment. I really need a good WW, but I don't have the time to run around and get all of the parts needed for any of the other WW's, e.g. 'Face Melter', 'Dischord'.

How much damage does this thing do?
Is it worth getting?
And is there any other Wonder Weapon that I can easily get with more damage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, the point of the Frostbite (or Forge Freeze before you upgrade it, as mentioned in [the wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Forge_Freeze)) is not to dish out damage. The purpose of this weapon is to *freeze* opponents. As mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/CODZombies/comments/5ejnop/forge_freeze_in_depth_usage_guide/), you will do minimal damage with the Forge Freeze. However, you can use it to farm a ridiculous number of points:

> The weapon itself is point farming incarnate. It gives you twenty points per hit and fourty points per freeze. In my head I've dubbed the gun a 'split-beam-weapon'. Essentially, the freeze ray it shoots out can split into three separate ends, freezing up to 3 Zombies per shot. These ends auto target depending on zombies that are within your circular crosshair. **Be warned, the weapon may seem like it does no damage but in actual fact it does. It took a lot of testing with a single zombie over the course of an hour but I eventually discovered that Zombies do sustain a tiny amount of damage per freeze.** Keep this in mind if you're going hard on one or two Zs.
>
> As previously stated the Forge Freeze gives you 20 points for a hit and 40 points for a freeze, with a potential of 3 zombies hit/frozen per shot. If you play optimally and get lucky enough to freeze all 3 zombies every time you fire you could make an upper limit of 30,000 points per 250 rounds, which is how much the Forge Freeze contains. If you got super unlucky and only ever hit one zombie and never froze him you're looking at a lower limit of 5000. Neither of those numbers will happen, but you will land somewhere between the two.

The guide also mentions the upgrade to the Frostbite isn't really worth it:

> Upgrading the Forge Freeze is a pretty useless endeavour. The points it gives out are the same, it has a higher chance to freeze and it has more ammo. By all accounts, you would imagine that would make the upgrade a good thing, but really there's just no point. If you've done things correctly you'll have around 20,000 points after buying the ammo replenish with your tickets anyway, and that's more than enough to get everything done.

So all in all, if you're looking for a pure damage weapon, you're probably better off going with a different weapon, but if you want to rack up a lot of points (and have a bit of time on your hands), the Forge Freeze seems pretty handy.

Comment: Thanks @Vemonus. Is there a Wonder Weapon that you'd recomend for pure damage?

Comment: @RhysB2002 unfortunately I don't actually play the game, so I can't give a recommendation, sorry :(